# What is the meaning of "length of my face" in : "Don't be disheartened Mr Pycroft : said my new acquaintance, seeing the length of my face"

Tags: expressions, literature

I am quoting from The Memoirs of Sherlock Holmes, The Stockbroker's Clerk by Arthur Conan Doyle.
I gather from the context that that Mr Pycroft is referring to his disappointment by "the length of my face" but I couldn't find the expression in dictionaries or even on google.

Comment: Look up 'long face' in an online dictionary. Have you never sung "Don't have a face like a coffee pot ...'? It's meant to make people smile.

Comment: Thank you I found it

Comment: Someone who looks disappointed or more generally glum is said to "have a long face". This is because the muscles in the face relax so that the lines of the face turn down making it look longer. It has nothing to do with the actual shape of the face at all.

Comment: Thank you I wasn't looking for the right word in the dictionary

Comment: Horse goes into a bar, the barman asks it "Why the long face?"

Comment: @WeatherVane I thought about adding that one to my comment, then I got a bit po-faced and didn't. Glad you did though.

Comment: @BoldBen you and the horse would get along fine :)

Comment: @WeatherVane Neigh lad.